# sprintf combine zero padding & decimals

Tags: google-apps-script, printf

I'm working on a Google script that uses formatString(template, args) and the docs say it uses the '%'-style formatting (similar to sprintf). What I'm trying to get is a three digit number with zero padding, plus three decimal places.

25.1 = 025.100

I've tried using "%03d.3f" but that doesn't work. It gives me the three decimal places, but not the leading zeros. I tried combining strings:

```
txt += Utilities.formatString("%03d", data[row][j]);
txt += Utilities.formatString("%.3f", data[row][j]);
```

But that leaves a leading 0 on the second part, so I get 0250.100. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question for some amount of time, so I'll just post this as a comment...

Found my own problem. I didn't realize the '.' counts when determining length. The solution ended up being

    `Utilities.formatString("%07.3f", 10.15);`

Which gives you '010.150'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being  `Utilities.formatString("%07.3f", 10.15);` Which gives you '010.150'